# I think python is overwriting my vtable (c++ extension)

Tags: c++, python

I'm writing a C++ python extension and I've been experiencing a SIGSEGV whenever I call (from C++) a virtually-inherited method of a certain class that is also a PyObject (i.e. it has a PyObject_HEAD).

I finally remembered that python doesn't know anything about C++. Sure enough, GCC is putting a vtable pointer in the first 4 bytes of my object (you can tell because the first field of PyObject_HEAD is offset 4 bytes from the address of the object). When python INCREFs the object, it's actually altering the vtable pointer.

My question: what should I do to fix this? Moving the virtual methods to a subsidiary class would solve it, but it seems like admitting defeat. Any other thoughts / experiences?

(Python 2.7, GCC 4.7.2 on mingw32 / windows 7)

Comment: I think it's fair to say that your class is *not* a PyObject if the relevant structures at not at the beginning of the object's memory...

Comment: @oli it looks like a pyobject and quacks like a pyobject. I think the problem is the reverse: it's not a C++ virtual descendant class instance once python does its dirty work.

Comment: Why is it important for you to make your class a PyObject? Why can't you have a data member which is a struct starting with PyObject_HEAD?

Comment: I guess with some template magic you could create wrapper objects which allocate extra space for the Py part.

Comment: Who is responsible for deleting objects of your class? Is it the CPython memory manager (i.e. reference counting and garbage collection)?

Comment: @pts yes, python GC and refcounting need to work for this object

Comment: Embed a C++ class INTO your PyObject, possibly passing the PyObject* into your C++ class (as "self" member). Then your problems likely will vanish. Mixing CPython and C++ memory management is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't know about C++ but it does know about structures. So have Python call a pure C function that creates a structure. Instead the structure have a pointer to the C++ object. This way Python sees a pure C interface, but the implementation of the C interface creates a private internal object.

We actually do this on one of my projects. It works and it's pretty portable.

Comment: this is legit and I did something similar, but I'm looking for a third option -- maybe a feature that tells python the true offset of the class's PyObject_HEAD.